# ffmpeg doesn't work anymore after cpu and motherboard switch

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, powershell

I recently switched my motherboard and cpu (Intel to AMD). Since then, ffmpeg doesn't work anymore. I tried removing it and putting a new version in place, but no luck.

I'm running Windows 10, and I use ffmpeg by putting it in a specific folder and pointing my path to it, so I can call it in powershell/cmd. The call itself works fine and the conversion starts, but it also stops after a few seconds every time. This is the type of command I used to use:

```
ffmpeg -i .\test.mkv -preset fast -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -c:s copy -map 0 -map_metadata 0 -x265-params crf=22 .\test2.mkv
```

The main goal is to reencode movies to x265 and reduce their size without (drastically) reducing quality.

When I put loglevel to debug, I see nothing unusual, I could share any logs you want if you tell me which are useful.

I tried running the exact same command on other machines, even through wsl on the same machine, all work fine.

Does anyone have any idea what I could try? Anything that might cause this? Right now, I don't even know where to begin...

Thanks for your time!

Edit:
I reran with "-report" option, log file can be found here, I hope this helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4xjA6ZyqCExh7oNc3HMtpwQAeANlDkc/view

Edit 2: I just did a clean install of my windows, and the problem persists... Now I'm even more puzzled...

Comment: *"The call itself works fine and the conversion starts, but it also stops after a few seconds every time."* - What exactly happens? Are any errors or other output displayed? Also, just for clarity, are you using the latest updated Windows builds from [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for your reply (and reformatting my question)

I downloaded the latest build from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ yesterday yes.

Comment: "What exactly happens? Are any errors or other output displayed?"

None at all, it just freezes for a second or 2 and then stops and show the input prompt again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more attempts, I managed to fix my issue by resetting my bios to default so my overclock of both CPU and RAM was put back to default.

After that, ffmpeg runs fine in powershell.
I might try and see how far I can push it before it stops working, maybe it is only the RAM and not the CPU or vice versa, don't know, don't care right now, I'm just glad it's working again.

Edit: Re-enabled the CPU overclocking, and it still works. So the problem seems to be in the RAM overclocking.